# CreateProcess() Error

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
si.cb = sizeof(si);

LPCWSTR procName =(LPCWSTR)"D:\\test dir 1\\Calc.exe";
LPWSTR procArg   =(LPWSTR)"blacknull";

if(CreateProcess(procName,procArg,0,0,0,CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,0,0,&si,&pi))
{
    //do some work
}

printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
     system("Pause");
```

It keeps throwing Error(2)-> `The System cannot find the file specified`.

I don't know what's wrong.  I also tried to use "Calc.exe" which in the same Dir. but it's not working.

Comment: I doubt casting `LPSTR` to `LPWSTR` actually makes the conversion.

Comment: Either use `CreateProcessA` or pass pointers to wide strings (that is, pointers that *actually* point to wide strings) to the function.

Comment: Casting is how you hide errors, not fix them. Code like `(LPCWSTR)"whatever"` is *always* wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the `L` prefix to make a wide character string:

```
L"D:\\test dir 1\\Calc.exe";
```

Casting a string literal to a different character width does not make a string wider.

Comment: Casting away const-ness doesn't make the backing store writeable either. Had to downvote the answer. See [Harry Johnston's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8844654/1889329) for rationale.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the string type issue already pointed out, the second argument (lpCommandLine) must point to a writable buffer, not a constant string.  You can do this by declaring it as follows:

```
WCHAR procArg[] = L"blacknull";
```

This is [documented in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation."