# What is the correct input format for windows CopyFile?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to use the windows CopyFile function to copy one file and rename it as another in a different folder. However it always returns that there's a problem with the path even though the path I am giving it is correct and both file and folder exist. What am I doing wrong?

Using "C:\Dummy.png" as the source and "C:\Dest" as the destination.

```
void CreateDummyItemsAssetsPNG()
{
    string  DummyAsset;  
    string  dummyDestination; 

    cout<<"Please Provide dummy file asset that is a .png: "; 
    cin>>DummyAsset; 

    cout<<"Please Provide a Destination: "; 
    cin>>dummyDestination; 

    vector<string>::iterator itor; 
    string fullDest; 

    for(itor = listOfItems.begin(); itor<listOfItems.end(); ++itor)
    {
        fullDest.clear(); 
        fullDest = dummyDestination + "\\"+ (*itor)+".png"; 
        cout<<"Copy: "<<DummyAsset<<" TO: "<<fullDest<<endl; 
        if(!CopyFile(LPCTSTR(DummyAsset.c_str()),LPCTSTR(dummyDestination.c_str()),false) )
        {
            printf("Could not copy file.\n"); 
            cout<<GetLastError()<<endl; 
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Casting `c_str()` to `LPTSTR` [doesn't actually make it `TSTR`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844076/createprocess-error).

Comment: To expand on GSerg's comment: since you're using 8-bit strings, use CopyFileA instead of CopyFile.

Answer (score 5):

`CopyFile()` expects a file *name* as the second parameter, whereas you are only passing the destination *directory*. Specify the full name (which you seem to do in `fullDest`) and this should work.