# CreateProcess @ Unhandled exception when not using directly a string

Tags: c++, string, winapi, createprocess

I'm trying to use CreateProcess to open a game .exe but I'm having the unhandled exception error. I already figured out the problem and the solution, but I need to get the path for the second parameter of CreateProcess from a file dialog box (that part is done and works). The problem is:

For the second parameter of CreateProcess, I need to declare a variable with the value to it (the 2nd param), but if I "point" it to the variable of the path to the file selected in the file dialog box, it doesn't work anymore.

I'm sorry if this is a really dumb question, but I'm starting in C++.

The code that works is here:

```
    wchar_t szGameDir[] = L"PATH_TO_EXE";

    if ( CreateProcess (
        NULL,
        szGameDir, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
        NULL, NULL,
        &pstStartupInfo, &pstProcInfo ) )
```

But when I set szGameDir to the value of 'pszGameDir' (path to the EXE selected by the user), it gives the unhandled exception error...

```
wchar_t* szGameDir = pszGameDir;

if ( CreateProcess (
        NULL,
        szGameDir, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
        NULL, NULL,
        &pstStartupInfo, &pstProcInfo ) )
```

And this is where I initialize 'pszGameDir':

```
OPENFILENAME DialogBox;
ZeroMemory ( &DialogBox, sizeof(DialogBox) );

DialogBox.lStructSize       = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
DialogBox.hwndOwner         = NULL;
DialogBox.lpstrFilter       = L"Grand Theft Auto: Vice City (*.exe)\0*.exe\0";
DialogBox.lpstrFile         = (LPTSTR)this->pszGameDir;
DialogBox.nMaxFile          = MAX_PATH;
DialogBox.nMaxFileTitle     = sizeof ( L"gta-vc.exe" );
DialogBox.lpstrTitle        = L"Please, select 'gta-vc.exe'";
DialogBox.Flags             = 0x02000000 | 0x00001000 | 0x00000400 | 0x10000000 | 0x00020000 | 0x00000800 | 0x0000008;
DialogBox.nFileExtension    = (WORD)"exe";
DialogBox.lpstrDefExt       = L"exe";

return GetOpenFileName ( &DialogBox ) != 0 ? 1 : NULL;
```

Can someone help me? (Yes, I did search already, but honestly I haven't found about this specific thing, I wasn't able to fix it either..)

Comment: Can you show us how you're declaring `pszGameDir` and where you're pointing it to `szGameDir` as well? I have a suspicion that, you're declaring it but not initializing it.. then initializing one of them.. invalidating the other.

Comment: In addition to what @SimonWhitehead said, please don't specify `NULL` as the first parameter to `CreateProcess` as that can cause weird issues when the system tries to deduce the path to use and is forced to modify the string pointed to by the second parameter. Instead do it right, and pass the path to the executable as the first parameter. Read more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I declare 'pszGameDir' in a class as a public member (this is just a test project, I'll re-write everything so I'm not really worried about if variables are public or private): "LPTSTR pszGameDir;" - Then I initialize 'pszGameDir' in the 'GetVCPath' function which creates a file dialog box and uses 'GetOpenFileName' to set the right path to 'pszGameDir'. 'pszGameDir' holds the correct value, I outputted its value with MessageBox. Also, I'm not pointing pszGameDir to szGameDir, it's the other way around (or do you say it that way?): ( wchar_t* szGameDir = pszGameDir; ).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem here is in the declaration, but I can't find the correct way..

Comment: Please update your question with appropriate code. Code > words :)

Comment: Is what I wrote enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CreateProcess() Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844076/createprocess-error)

Comment: That is not exactly my problem, I think, Raymond. I said in the topic that I couldn't find about that specific thing (creating process from a variable that points to another, I have only found topics like these you mentioned). I know what is my problem, I just can't find how to do it..

Comment: That `pszGameDir` and `szGameDir` are both pointers with the same address value, while helpful to know, is meaningless unless that address is pointing to a *valid buffer*. As presented here, we have no way of knowing if that is the case. Both GetOpenFileDialog and CreateProcess require a *writable* address to valid memory. I hope for your sake one is provided, even indirectly.

Comment: I already said here that pszGameDir holds the correct value, if that's what you meant by "valid buffer". I also said that I'm just starting with C++ now so I don't have much experience. I know the problem is that the value is not writable for some reason, the problem is that I don't know how to make it writable. I edited the topic to add more code that may be helpful to solve the problem, or at least give me an idea of what I need to do (not to tell me that the variable must be writable, because I already realized that, as I said in the answer below), and then asked "Is what I wrote enough?".

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being just too dumb.

Comment: `pszGameDir` is a *pointer*. Consequently it holds an *address*. The address it hold should be that of a writable character buffer. An valid buffer would be either dynamically or static **allocated** memory that both pointers reference by way of the address stored within them. `TCHAR buffer[MAXPATH+1]; pszGameDir = buffer;` as a static example, `pszGameDir = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH+1]();` as a dynamic example. Bottom line: you'd *know it* if you were storing valid addresses to writable memory in your pointers `pszGameDir` and `szGameDir`, and it sounds like you are *not*, in fact, doing it.

Comment: Side note: `DialogBox` is a terrible name for a variable. It is actually a Windows API function name ([see `DialogBox()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452(v=vs.85).aspx)). What even more likely to cause head scratching, in WIN32 there are both a Unicode (DialogBoxW) and ANSI (DialogBoxA) versions of this function, with the symbol preprocess-substituted to one or the other depending on your compilation settings. It at least *appears* you're compiling with unicode, so your `OPENFILENAME` structure is actually called `DialogBoxW`.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig, this is just a test project, I think it isn't a big trouble if I use the same now, I'll re-write everything anyway. But still I thank you because I would most likely do the same mistake (didn't know there was a function with that name).

Answer (score 1):

CreateProcess needs the command line parameter to be writeable. Read the description of the argument at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

It has to be writeable, I am afraid.

Comment: I already got that ages ago, I just didn't realize how would I do it.. Sorry, but I'm newbie in C++..

Comment: @xxx You will need to copy the string into a writeable buffer. Use something like the built-in C `strcpy` function or [`lstrcpy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647490.aspx) (part of the Win32 API).

Comment: Okay, I've read all messages here and when I get home I'll change what has been mentioned here, and I'll keep trying to solve my problem.

Comment: I've been trying but I couldn't fix the problem.. AFAIK, LPTSTR is a non-const TCHAR (it also isn't a pointer, right?) so I don't see why do I still get the memory violation.. Here's what I tried:  LPTSTR szGameDir = {0};
 if ( SUCCEEDED(StringCchCopy( szGameDir, MAX_PATH, pszGameDir )) )
  MessageBoxW ( NULL, szGameDir, L"Msg", NULL );

Comment: pszGameDir is now a LPTSTR too (I forgot to remove the 'p' prefix, if it isn't a pointer).

Comment: Okay, I just tested this:  LPTSTR str = L"H:\\GTA Vice City\\gta-vc.exe";
 LPTSTR szGameDir = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];
 if ( SUCCEEDED(StringCchCopy( szGameDir, MAX_PATH, str )) )
  MessageBoxW ( NULL, szGameDir, L"Msg", NULL ); and it worked, so I'm sure the problem is that the variable is not writable.. but why not? It's a LPTSTR var like others, just that it's inside a class..