# Beginner C++ CreateProcess () Error 2

Tags: c++, winapi, command, createprocess, c++builder-xe

I am trying to create a process that send command to cmd.exe and receive Error 2,
Why? It's posible? How?

```
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    String pathexe = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe";
    String command= "notepad.exe";

    if(!CreateProcess(
            pathexe.c_str(),  // lpApplicationName
            command.c_str(),  // lpCommandLine
            NULL,   // lpProcessAttributes
            NULL,   // lpThreadAttributes
            FALSE,  // bInheritHandles
            0,      // dwCreationFlags
            NULL,   // lpEnvironment
            NULL,   // lpCurrentDirectory
            &si,    // lpStartupInfo
            &pi     // lpProcessInformation
            ))
    {
        AnsiString error = GetLastError();
        ShowMessage("Error: " + error);
    }
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

PD: 1) It is assumed that you can use CreateProcess () for this purpose, I should not do it with ShellExecute () or system().
2) I have read about it in the forum and can not find a solution to this error, there are many answers to similar questions but do not address the error, other functions are proposed, or mix with the route command.
3) I do not think that issue permits because I built while the manifest.
4) I currently use C ++ Builder, in win7, 32bits but not important.
5) I guess the issue will be voted as negative and duplicate (as usual) but the proposed testing examples also receive errors.
Thanks to all

FIRST CONCLUSIONS:

Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

Link funtion: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx
    Link error: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

With error 2: check syntax, file path and existence.

works:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    String command = "notepad.exe";

    if(!CreateProcess(
            NULL,   // lpApplicationName
            commmand.c_str(), // lpCommandLine
            NULL,   // lpProcessAttributes
            NULL,   // lpThreadAttributes
            FALSE,  // bInheritHandles
            0,      // dwCreationFlags
            NULL,   // lpEnvironment
            NULL,   // lpCurrentDirectory
            &si,    // lpStartupInfo
            &pi     // lpProcessInformation
            ))
    {
        AnsiString error = GetLastError();
        ShowMessage("Error: " + error);
    }
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

This example works also for exe

```
String command = "cd C:\\sample\\calc.exe";
```

But no with cmd´s general commands, there must be a way to send commands to cmd as:

```
notepad.exe && cd C:\sample\ && sample1.txt
```

THANKS TO ALL

Comment: You do know that [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns an *integer* value, not a string?

Comment: Are you sure? if I try to get int of GetLastError() no error is displayed on ShowMessage(),  but if I try to AnsiString display 2...

Comment: Follow the link to the MSDN reference. It returns a `DWORD`. If you try to use `+` between a string literal and an integer (like in `"Error: " + 2`), you are doing pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"` should be `"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"`.

Comment: Executing *notepad.exe* through the command interpreter *cmd.exe* is awkward. I would assume that *cmd.exe* expects the path to its executable image (`"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"`) as the first argument on the command line. You are passing `"notepad.exe"`. If you provide both the application name and a command line, copy the application name as the first argument to the command line, properly quoting it. Or simply omit the application name, and pass a command line only.

Comment: With "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe" start cmd.exe (open the shell) but not yet run the command

Comment: ok, it is a simple example, and it is awkward, but when becomes complicated ... anyway if I spend the first argument as null nor run... also I tried somethig like: cd path && notepad.exe and no. How should you do it ?, as it is easy and awkward

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateProcess() Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844076/createprocess-error)

Comment: @KenWhite: The questions are unrelated. The call in the question you linked to failed, because it was casting an ANSI string to a Unicode string. This is not the issue in this question.

Comment: @IInspectable: No, they're not. They're both about CreateProcess() failing with error 2 (file not found). There's also working code (once that string casting issue is addressed) for CreateProcess() in that post.

Comment: @KenWhite: The fail with the same error code, for different reasons. I pointed out the problem with this question in my first comment above.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `AnsiString` is a class type, not a string pointer.  One of the constructors converts an integer into a string, presumably C++ is using that one.

Comment: @hexadecimal This might seem like a strange question, but have you read the documentation?

Comment: "there must be a way to send commands to cmd" - yes, there is; did you read my answer, which explains exactly how to do that?

Comment: @David Heffernan It is not much more difficult to include here a link to documentation that only perform such questions.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to run this command:

```
cmd notepad
```

(You aren't doing that quite right, either; the lpCommandLine argument should include the entire string, not just `notepad`, and you haven't quoted the backslashes properly.)

But even once you fix those problems, it won't work, because you've got the syntax wrong.  You'll find it won't work if typed on the command line either!

Instead, try:

```
String pathexe = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
String command= "cmd /c notepad.exe";
```

The `/c` option means "run this command".  You can use `/k` instead if you want the command window to stay open after the command has finished, though it's unusual for a program to do so.

One final note: I'm assuming here than `notepad` is just a stand-in for a more complicated command.  If you actually want to run notepad, or any other executable, you shouldn't be invoking `cmd.exe` at all:

```
String command= "notepad";

if(!CreateProcess(
        NULL,  // lpApplicationName
        command.c_str(),  // lpCommandLine
        ...
```

You only need to call on `cmd.exe` if you need to run a built-in command, or a composite command line.

(Actually, calling `cmd.exe` is considered poor practice even in those cases; in Windows, you are generally expected do that sort of thing for yourself via the API rather than farming out the job to the command interpreter.  But there are edge cases, and your mileage may vary.)